# how can i save some information that i got in views to one of fields in models - django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

this is my views.py :
i want save type in device field in model

```
class GetDeviceMixin( object):
    def setup(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        super().setup( request, *args, **kwargs)
        type= request.META['HTTP_USER_AGENT']
        print(type)
        return type


class RegisterView(GetDeviceMixin , generic.CreateView):
    form_class = CustomUserCreationForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy("register")
    template_name = "man/man.html"
```

and this is my models.py

```
class account(AbstractBaseUser):
    first_name= models.CharField(max_length=20,verbose_name="first name")
    device = models.CharField(verbose_name="device" , max_length=100)
```

this is my forms.py:

```
class GetReq(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = account
        fields = ['device',]
```

Comment: Don't use `type` as a variable, because its name is a defined function in python and your code would overwrite that.
Instead use  `_type` , `device_type` or a different name.

Answer (score 0):

First, pop [Classy CBVs](https://ccbv.co.uk/projects/Django/2.2/django.views.generic.edit/CreateView/) onto your browser bookmark list ...

I'm assuming that you want to use a form, either to get other information from the user, or to allow the user to override the automatically determined value of device. In this case, you want to pass it as the initial value for device to the form

Now, look at CreateView to work out what to subclass. `get_initial()` looks hopeful, so

```
def get_initial(self):
    initial = super().get_initial()
    initial['device'] = self.device_type # as per the comment!
    return initial
```

You should now see a form with the automatically determined value as the default value

If the intent was to get *other* fields of the model from the user and to always forcibly insert the automatically determined device_type, you would instead subclass `form_valid`

```
def form_valid(form):
    obj = form.save( commit=False)
    obj.device = self.device_type
    obj.save()
```